# Proof on $F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ uniform convergence and differentiability

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f$ be a function of $C^{\infty}$ class, such that $f(0)=0=f'(0)$. Prove that if $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\ ,$$
then $F(x)\in\mathbb{R}$ and $F$ is differentiable infinitely many times.

I'm aware of merely one theorem that may be helpful in this case, which is that if $\left(f_n\right)$ is a function sequence that is convergent for some $x_0$ and $\left(f'_n\right)$ is uniformly convergent, then $\left(f_n\right)$ is also uniformly convergent (...).

We know that $F(0)$ is finite. Then for $$G(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}f'\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$$ we also have $G(0)<\infty$. If I could show $G$ is uniformly convergent, it would mean $F$ is uniformly convergent and $F'=G$.

Now, I'm not sure if what I'm about to do is correct, but I'd like to use the dfinition of near uniform convergence. $f\in C^{\infty}$, so $f'\in C^{\infty}$. Every fucntion continuous on closed interval is uniformly continuous, and in result, is Lipschtiz. So for $x\in[a,b]$ and some $M_1,M_2\in\mathbb{R}$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}f''\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n^2}f'\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{M_2-M_1}{n^2} < \infty$$

This means, that by Weierstrass theorem $G'$ is uniformly convergent $\Rightarrow G$ is u.c., which in turn basing on above-mentioned theorem again, gives us uniform convergence of $F$.

Mmm, as I look at this proof, it seems dubious... Moreover, I didn't include differentiability of $F$. Please, help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ exists (use l'Hôpital), it follows that $|f(x)|<Cx^2$ for small $x$. Because in dealing with convergence one can always delete finitely many terms, we start with some big $N$, so $\frac{x}{n}$ is small, to use this inequality. It follows that $F(x)<\infty$:

$$\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\right|\leq Cx^2\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$$

Because $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{x}$ exists, it follows that $|f'(x)|<C|x|$ for small $x$. Now we see that $F'(x)<\infty$.

$$\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n}f'\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\right|\leq C\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{|x|}{n^2}<\infty$$

Now we want to show that $F^{(k)}(x)<\infty$, $k\geq2$. Here we use that $|f^{(k)}(x)|<C$ for small $x$

$$\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{1}{n^k}f^{(k)}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\right|\leq C\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{1}{n^k}$$

In your post you mention uniform convergence, but that is not required to answer the question. If we for example take $f(x)=x^2$, then $F(x)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}x^2$, but the difference between every partial sum and the limit function is not bounded.

Comment: It certainly works for $x$ in some interval, but does it also mean $F(x)\in \mathbb{R}$ for all $x$ ?

Comment: Yes, because every $x$ lies in some (sometimes big) interval. Also note that $\mathbb{R}$ is infinite, but every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is finite.

Comment: Ok, but can I differentiate the way you did without the knowledge of $F$ uniform convergence? You wrote about small $x$, so this inequality holds only for them. Or did you mean to bound the sum with a converrgent one which varies depending on $x$? If that's the case, I think I did pretty much the same.

Comment: No matter how big $x$ is, you can always choose $N$ way bigger, so $\frac{x}{n}$ is small and you can use the inequality. And yes, it is allowed to differentiate without uniform convergence, but you have to show that the derivative converges. Indeed I bounded the sum with a convergent one, depending on $x$. It seems you use uniform convergence on every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, which is good, but your proof is hard to understand. Which quantity do you estimate?

Comment: Ok, nevermind my solution, it's insufficient. I understand your point now, but still, how do you know $|f^{(k)}(x)|<C$ ?

Comment: Since $f$ is arbitrary often differentiable, $f^{(k)}$ is continuous. Therefore it is bounded on some compact interval around $0$. For any $x$, there exists a $N$ such that $\frac{x}{n}$ lies in that interval, for $n>N$. The terms from $n=0$ to $n=N$ add up to a finite quantity, and the terms $n>N$ also do. Do you understand the trick to delete the first $N$ terms, and why it is allowed?

Comment: I do, I do, it's just that I needed to think over it a little bit. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16668/discussion-between-thijs-and-jules).